# How to hide a modal and show another on a single click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, arrow-functions

I want to hide login modal and show register modal on a single button click. The code is only performing one of the either function.

```
<div><p onClick={() => {
          setShowModal(false);
          setShowModalr(true);
          }}>register now!</p>
           {showModalr && (
                  <RegisterModal
                    showModalr={showModalr}
                    setShowModalr={setShowModalr}
                  />
                )}
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres many better packages than that...

Try https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/

Or https://material-ui.com/components/modal/

Or https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal/

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question.  these two statements  setShowModal(false);
          setShowModalr(true); are not getting executed as expected. The issue is independent of the package I use.

Comment: sorry i misunderstood the question anyways can you add the code of Registermodel or is it a package?